# Can a QR code be processed / validated only by a certain device?

Tags: php, validation, security, qr-code

Hi I was wondering if it's possible to make sure only a specific device can validate a QR code?

For example I have a e ticket with a QR code. The QR code is going to be used to check people in to a specific ship they are going to board. Workers have a certain device which they can scan the QR codes with. This device only may validate these QR codes.

The reason I'm asking is that we don't want random users with random smartphones to scan the QR codes and trigger a URL that does the check-in and control when they aren't there and the date is not the date of the ticket and is not the device that should have validate the QR code.

I have no idea if there is a way to send a devices unique number along with the QR code or that the code on the specific URL can read out the information of the device ?

We are using PHP to create this web system. Has anybody done something like this before or does know how to deal with this issue ?

Looking forward on some information since I haven't found any useful information regarding issue's like these.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: at its core, the issue isn't with QR codes, but rather with a severe design flaw in your application.**

QR codes are standardized and meant to be somewhat ubiquitous. It's their ubiquity that has driven users' familiarity with them (how they look, what they do, how they can use them) and, thus, their adoption. **There is no widely-available QR code standard that includes provisions for white-listing only certain devices to scan the resulting image.** Even if there was, there would be numerous problems with this approach:

- QR codes are somewhat *permanent* - they are usually affixed somewhere in the real world. If information about *which* devices were allowed to scan it could be embedded in the QR code itself, what would happen if you wanted to authorize a new device? It'd be financially and temporally impractical to replace **every** last QR just to allow this one new device.
- QR codes can only store a finite amount of data - dependent on how many devices you'd actually want to be "authorized" to use a code, the authorization information could fill to a maximum capacity quite quickly.
- Both the bullets above are a bit moot, as QR codes are evaluated by the scanning device - it would be somewhat trivial to patch over and bypass these restrictions on almost any device (similar to how you would never fully trust a validation happening on a client, and verify the data received on the server side).

It seems like you're trying to solve what appears to be a design flaw in your application by seeking to arbitrarily modify this widely-used standard to meet your specific use case.

---

## Possible mitigations

1. **Continue using a QR code tied to a specific URL, but only allow requests to change data/state when *authenticated***. Have your users navigate their mobile browser to the application in question and authenticate such that subsequent requests to the application (opening the URLs with the QRs) will be authorized correctly, and those without a valid authorization are greeted with a lovely `401 Unauthorized`.

   (It's somewhat concerning that you've implied both that (a) the state changes triggered by accessing these URLs are somewhat sensitive (in that you don't want random people scanning them), and (b) there's not already any system of authentication to prevent anyone, by either scanning the code or simply guessing the URL, from modifying this sensitive data on your server. I'd strongly suggest reviewing this design with someone from a security perspective to mitigate these risks *before* your data is tampered with by a third party.)
2. Change the design so the QR code being scanned is simply arbitrary textual data - similar to that of the numerical encoding accomplished with [UPC barcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code) - and have the authorized users leverage a custom client application that can take that arbitrary data and generate the proper API calls/URL opening(s) in the background.
3. Write your own standard similar to QR codes, and a corresponding client application to consume them.

   As with most "is it possible?"-esque questions, the answer is usually "yes", and the variables are moreso things like time, funding, and knowledge (among others). It's unlikely in most all cases that you'd have a team with enough of all three to be able to pull this off in a reliable and secure manner, but if you did, your researchers might be able to write something completely new that could integrate this "authorization" as you wish to design it.

   However, they'd still have to overcome the shortcomings I mentioned in my bullet points above for this to work, which would require supremely novel approaches to the problem usually only found in academic sectors and organizations with "skunkworks"-type departments. (Read: this is probably not what you want to do).

All in all, when using QR codes like this, the onus of security will be entirely on the receiving server/application. There is nothing in the QR code standard that will perform this authorization/authentication layer *for* you.

Aside from the three mitigations here, I'd also encourage you to take an even further step back to really evaluate whether QR codes are even the appropriate tool for this task.

Comment: Ok @esqew thank you for your well formed answer. At the moment we aren't bound to anything since we are still in designing and thinking on how the system should work. So this is a good to know. Also  I'm wondering how current companies do this with barcodes or QR codes, are these ticketing systems/companies not facing the same issue's ? 

For example they also use a scanner which doesn't have the capability of login in on to a system. So just wondering how they do it ? We can't use local bounded systems since boats can departure basically from any place.